# Pagination Error on Admin (You do not have sufficient permissions)

Tags: admin, pagination, permissions

Hi everybody and tks in advance for your help!
I have a plugin and I was trying to do some pagination for a custom query. Everything seems to work fine, but when I click on page 2 (or whatever not being "1"), wordpress says

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

I believe that this error is because with this pagination method that I was trying, the URL is:

> /wp-admin/admin.php?page=lismovim-withdraw-slug/page/2/

So, I suppose that WP doesn't reconigze this address. Any ideas? Maybe some other way to do the pagination? I really need some help, I was surfing the internet quite long now and couldn't find any solution.
Here's my code:

```
function listado_movimientos(){


    echo '<p><strong>LISTADO DE MOVIMIENTOS APROBADOS/DECLINADOS<strong></p>';
    echo '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped axdepositbycash">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 15px">
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>FECHA</td>
                <td>USUARIO</td>
                <td>NOMBRE</td>
                <td>CANTIDAD</td>
                <td>Nº CUENTA</td>
                <td>ESTADO</td>
            </tr>';

    $rows_per_page = 10;
    $current = (intval(get_query_var('paged'))) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

    global $wpdb; 
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix. "withdraw";
    $result2=$wpdb->get_results("select * from $table_name where status='aprobado'");


    $pagination_args = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
        'format' => '',
        'total' => ceil(sizeof($result2)/$rows_per_page),
        'current' => $current,
        'show_all' => false,
        'type' => 'plain',
        );


        $pagination_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg('s',get_pagenum_link(1) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged');


        if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) )
        $pagination_args['add_args'] = array('s'=>get_query_var('s'));

        echo paginate_links($pagination_args);

        $start = ($current - 1) * $rows_per_page;
        $end = $start + $rows_per_page;
        $end = (sizeof($result2) < $end) ? sizeof($result2) : $end;

        echo '<br />';
        echo '<br />';

        for ($i=$start;$i < $end ;++$i ) {
        $r2 = $result2[$i];
        echo  '<tr>
                <td>'.$r2->id.'</td>
                <td>'.$r2->wdate.'</td>
                <td> '.$r2->fname. "  " . $r2->lastname.'</td>
                <td>'.$r2->name.'</td>
                <td>'.$r2->amt.'</td>
                <td>'.$r2->acno.'</td>
                <td>'.$r2->status.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

}

[Here is the original snippet, where I found how to do the pagination in the first place.](http://wordpress.mcdspot.com/2010/11/25/pagination-using-paginate_links/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `base` argument for [`paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) should be:

```
admin_url( 'admin.php?page=lismovim-withdraw-slug&paged=%_%' )
```

... where `%_%` is replaced by `format`, which should be:

```
'%#%'
```

... which is replaced by the page number.

Comment: Tks! It works just fine but now I have another issue. The URL seems to work fine (in the permissions "way") but pagination is not working at all. When I try to see the value of this line:
$current = (intval(get_query_var('paged'))) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
It's always getting me "1", so... that means that "get_query_var" is not working to read de "paged" parameter... Am I doing something wrong here? Tks again!!

Comment: No, `get_query_var` works around `$wp_query`, which is only prepared/ready to use on posts-related admin pages. Use `$paged = isset( $_REQUEST['paged']) ? max( 1, ( int ) $_REQUEST['paged']  ) : 1;`

Comment: Oh man, I must say you really really save my day. It works exactly as you said !!! Thanks you very much!!! Hope in the future I can help you with something!!