# Custom admin page pagination permissions error

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

I have a custom page pulling in users and I'm using some pagination.

It works fine if I look at the page on the front end of the site but when I look at the site within the admin area within a basic plugin I've made, it doesn't work and I get a permissions error "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

This is the code below, I have no idea why it's not working, but if anyone has any clues I'd really  appreciate it,

Thanks!

```
    <?php 
       $total_users = count_users();
       $total_users = $total_users['total_users'];
       $paged = get_query_var('paged');
       $number = 50;
    ?>

    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'display_name',
            'count_total' => 'true',
            'role' => 'subscriber',
            'offset' => $paged ? ($paged) * $number : 0,
            'number' => $number,
        );?>



        <?php
            $blogusers = get_users($args);?>

        <?php // Array of WP_User objects.
            foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {?>

            <?php $userId = $user->ID;?>

            <?php  echo '<input type="text" value="' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '">';?>



            <div id="content">

            <h2>Completed Courses</h2>


                    <!-- COMPLIANCE-->



                        <?php
                            $post_args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
                                'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
                                'start_date'     => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '-365 days' ) ),
                                'tax_query' => array(

                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                                        'field'    => 'slug',
                                        'terms'    => 'compliance',
                                        ),
                                            ),

                                            'meta_query' => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'key' => 'associated_people',
                                                    'value' => '"' . $userid . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ); ?>

                        <!-- MEMBERSHIP A -->                       

                        <?php if( rcp_is_active() && 2 == rcp_get_subscription_id() ) : ?>

                            <?php
                            $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                                <table style="width:100%">      
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Compliance</td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?php
                                        if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                    ?>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></td>
                                            <td><?php the_field('cpd_credits'); ?></td>
                                        </tr>

                        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


                        <?php

                        $total_credit = 0;

                        $post_list = new wp_query( $post_args ); ?>

                        <table style="width:100%">      

                            <?php
                                if( $post_list->have_posts() ) : while( $post_list->have_posts() ) : $post_list->the_post();
                                    $cur_credit = get_field('cpd_credits');
                                    $total_credit += $cur_credit;
                            ?>


                            <?php endwhile; else : ?>
                            <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td <?php if($total_credit >= 2): ?> style="background-color:#009137;" <?php endif; ?> <?php if($total_credit < 2): ?> style="background-color:#f50c1a;" <?php endif; ?>>
                                    Total: <?php echo $total_credit;?> of 2 in the last 12 months
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            </table>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <!-- END OF MEMBERSHIP A -->

 <?php $pl_args = array(
     'base'     => add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
     'format'   => '',
     'total'    => floor($total_users / $number),
     'current'  => max(1, $paged),
  );

  // for ".../page/n"
  if($GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->using_permalinks())
    $pl_args['base'] = user_trailingslashit(trailingslashit(get_pagenum_link(1)).'page/%#%/', 'paged');


  echo paginate_links($pl_args);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this using another post - [Pagination Error on Admin (You do not have sufficient permissions)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/227796/pagination-error-on-admin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions)

Basically I needed to changed the $paged argument to $paged = isset( $_REQUEST['paged']) ? max( 1, ( int ) $_REQUEST['paged'] ) : 1;

and the $pl_args argument to $pl_args['base'] = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=cpd-admin-page&paged=%_%' );